# is there a destructive version of tcl linsert?

Tags: list, tcl

Say I have a huge list, and I want to insert a value, w/o creating a copy (performance). If one want to append to the end, one uses lappend. Is there a way to do the equivalent for the beginning, and to any internal element?
I.e. This code:

```
set k { 1 2 }
destr_ins k 0 0 ; #dummy proc name
puts [lindex $k 0]
```

Would yield the result:

```
>0
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking for a way to insert an element at the beginning without copying the whole list ?

Comment: Yes. And maybe for any location.

Comment: Currently, `linsert` can do the insertion at any index, but it will not directly affect the list, instead it will return a new list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no destructive `linsert`, but you can fake one using the “`K`” trick (named after one of the combinators, though that isn't needed any more):

```
set myList [linsert $myList[set myList {}] 0 "a b c"]
#                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The bytecode engine (plus the reference management code) can effectively optimize that to a destructive operation, provided the list isn't shared elsewhere. If it is shared, then a copy is required anyway. The code is fastest inside a procedure.

It works by putting the list on the bytecode engine's stack, removing the reference that was held by the variable (assuming no traces) and then letting the `linsert` code work normally; it's got a code-path for optimized operation with unshared objects.